# Why does `__all__` break function annotations?

Tags: python

I had the following files:

```
# package/sub1/obj1.py
class Obj1:
    def __init__(self, spam:int):
        self.spam = spam

# package/sub2/obj2.py
from ..sub1.obj1 import Obj1
class Obj2(Obj1):
    pass
```

After implementing the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38907151/what-do-i-need-to-place-in-my-init-py-files-to-simplify-this-packages-int/38907428#38907428) by placing `__all__ = ['sub1', 'sub2']` in `package/__init__.py`, and `from .obj* import Obj*` in the other two subfolders' `__init__.py`, I got invalid syntax errors pointing at the function annotation colon when I attempted to import the package. Removing the function annotations fixed the errors, as did removing the assignment to `__all__`.

Why?

Comment: Sounds like it belongs to https://bugs.python.org/ really

Comment: Nope, I'm a baaaad programmer. I forgot to activate the virtual environment, so it was running Python 2.7 instead of 3.5.